# App not working while generating signed apk and installing in real device

Tags: android, apk, signed-apk

I made an app and tested everything. I was working fine in emulators and in USB-connected devices but did not work when generating signed apk file. I have made the app with both disabled/enabled instant run and it still didn't work.

I also tried uninstalling (for all users) and reinstalling the apk, still the issue remained (but application works fine with build apk). I have possibly tried all solutions available in similar posts but I can't find a solution, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more detailed of what you use to determine what is the problem.

Comment: The exact problem i am facing now is , after installing the app, the app openend and just closed again automatically .(not showing any message like app crashed)

Comment: Before opening the application on mobile, open up Android Studio and the logs terminal. Then open the application and if it crashes, the error logs will be displayed on Android Studio's terminal. You can then easily interpret why your application is not working on that mobile

Comment: Did you use proguard while generating signed build?

Comment: yes i have used proguard

Comment: Looking at the [logcat output](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) would be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding these 2 lines in my `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }

-keep class android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider { *; }
```

I have used search view in my activity, so I needed these library files to work when generating a signed apk. However I don't know why without including these files my app worked perfectly in emulators and in devices with usb debugging and not showing any errors in logcat files - it made it difficult to understand the problem.